# how getback source code file of app?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an app in my iPhone. Now i want to get source code of that app.My mean that how get source file of app? what is the processor so that i get information of app which is in my iphone?

Comment: Did you write the app or is it from someone else?

Comment: You cannot legally obtain a copy of someone else's sourcecode off your phone of a downloaded app (even if it is under a GPL or similar license because it's Apple).

Comment: @sandro Meier hi it from someone else. u get my another mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. If you wrote the application, hopefully you didn't delete the source code... if it isn't, it's not yours to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If this app was made with xcode then you canot get the source off the app as its compiled to a native binary format, the only possible way is to disassemble but you have to be a good knowledge of assembly language to understand the code.

If this app was made with another tool maybe it can be possible but I dont think it would be easy.

Comment: how i see assembly code?

Comment: You will need some disassembler tool like Hopper Disassembler